# how do I get data from a text file and save it into a string?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

How do I get data from a text file and save it into a string?

For example, my text file has the numbers 1, 4, 5, 6, 8, and 10.4. These numbers can be on the same line or on separate lines. I want to concatenate them into a string, like so: `1 4 5 6 8 10.4`

```
import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class f {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int count = 0;
        double totalcount = 0;
        double average = 0;
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner file;
        String input = "";
        String test = "";

        double[] array1 = new double[100];

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Enter name of file or enter quit to exit");
            input = read.next();
            if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
                break;
            }

            try {
                file = new Scanner(new File(input));
                if (!file.hasNextLine()) {
                    System.out.println(input + " file is empty");
                }

                while (file.hasNext()) {
                    totalcount = totalcount + file.nextDouble();
                    count++;
                }
                while (file.hasNext()) {
                    test = test + (" ") + file.next();
                }

                System.out.println("bla" + test);

                average = totalcount / count;

                DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
                df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);

                System.out.println("\nCount: " + count);
                System.out.println("Total: " + df.format(totalcount));
                System.out.println("Average: " + df.format(average));
                System.out.println();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println(input + " doesn't exist");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My code does not work correctly.

Comment: Sounds great. Any errors so far with this request?

Comment: Well this is all I have so far but it doesnt work. 
while (file.hasNext()) {
test = test + (" ") + file.next();
}

Comment: Can you please show a [mcve] in the question itself? Please **[edit]**

Comment: I just posted what I have so far, it is kind of a mess, my objective is to get a file name from a user then save the contents of a file to a string to then process.

Comment: You exhausted the whole scanner after the first `while (file.hasNext()) {`

Comment: Is your goal to read an entire file into a string, or read it word by word / number by number?

Comment: If all you want is the string. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-do-i-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file but I think you actually want a list of integers, it seems

Comment: youre right haha, I just combined the two but the problem now is that the while loop just reads one line and skips one so instead of 1 2 3 4 5 6 it prints 1 3 5

Comment: Also, there's this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213916/reading-integers-from-file-into-an-arraylist

Comment: I think your skipping problem is mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo

Comment: @EmmanoelD97 I understand this: Numbers in text file can be separated by one white space or by one line break. Numbers can be integer or decimal. Numbers in string variable are separed by one white space. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine, the problem is, you trying to access content of your file two times.after first `while loop` , the `hasnext()` method will return false.because you already accessed all the element in first `while` loop.
so it will not execute -

```
                while (file.hasNext()) {
                test = test + (" ") + file.next();
                }
```

Other than that your code is fine.
if you want store it in string also then do small modification in your first `while loop` as below-

```
while (file.hasNext()) {
      Double d=file.nextDouble();
      test = test + (" ")+d;
      totalcount = totalcount + d;
      count++;
 }
```

I think this will give you what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Hello i think below code will be useful for you ,as per your question i have txt file with data , first i am getting the location of file & then i am trying to get the content , at last i am printing it to the console

```
File f = new File("D:\\temp.txt");

    String content11 = FileUtils.readFileToString(f);

      System.out.println(content11);
```

Comment: It's not that simple. The numbers in the file can be on separate lines, or delimited by any type of whitespace.

Comment: have you tried my code ? if yes then tell me the output you are getting , if no then try & check...