# Reading integers from a textfile into an arraylist

Tags: java

I've read these two stack overflow posts: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303913/java-reading-integers-from-a-file-into-an-array) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213916/reading-integers-from-file-into-an-arraylist). I've followed the answers and am still getting no where.

I'm trying to read in a text file ([this one](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vldNboGWbjeBAR6JyyqAlNyLb3-FN7Lv)) and store it in an ArrayList. But when i go ahead and print the contents of the ArrayList to the console, nothing is returned...

Any help would be appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    ArrayList<Integer> test = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    Scanner textFileOne = new Scanner(new File("ChelseaVector.txt"));

    while (textFileOne.hasNext()) {
        if(textFileOne.hasNextInt()) {
            test.add(textFileOne.nextInt());
        } else {
        textFileOne.next();
        }
    }
    textFileOne.close();

    System.out.println(test);   
}
```

Comment: It's probably due to file's structure. Notice, that the contents of `"ChelseaVector.txt"` are enclosed in square brackets (`[]`). Try removing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to skip the `[` character at the beginning of the file, and define your delimiter as `]`:

```
Scanner textFileOne = 
    new Scanner(new File("ChelseaVector.txt")).useDelimiter(", ").skip("\\[");
```

Comment: Yes, but i get an exception of: Unclosed character class near index 0 [

Comment: @FeelingLikeAJabroni arg, forgot to escape it. Edited and fixed.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you... Can i add the replace() method to remove the [ ]?

Comment: It misses the last digit at least as per my observation.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> originalFile = new ArrayList<>(Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("ChelseaVector.txt")));
List<Integer> formattedFile = new ArrayList<>();

for (String line : originalFile ) {
    String newLine = line.replaceAll("[", "").replaceAll("]", "").replaceAll(" ", "");
    List<String> numbers = Arrays.asList(String.join(","));
    formattedFile.addAll(numbers);
}

System.out.println(formattedFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ArrayList<Integer> test = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        Scanner textFileOne = new Scanner(new File("ChelseaVector.txt")).useDelimiter(",");

        while (textFileOne.hasNext()) {
            if (textFileOne.hasNextInt()) {
                test.add(textFileOne.nextInt());
            } else {
                int number=Integer.parseInt(textFileOne.next().replaceAll("[\\[\\]]","").trim());
                test.add(number);
            }
        }
        textFileOne.close();

        System.out.println(test);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your file contains one line only, you shouldn't be using a loop in my opinion.
The following code should work if you're using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8)

```
String[] strings = Files.lines(Paths.get("ChelseaVector.txt")).findFirst().split("\\D+");
List<Integer> ints = Arrays.stream(strings).map(Integer::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
```